# JPA JPQL - Query that returns if child object is not used (no primary key / foreign key relationship) and can be deleted

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

Spring Boot / MySQL / JPA / JPQL

I have an app that I would like to allow for the deletion of an object as long as it isn't being referend by another object (primary key / foreign key relationship)

For the UI I only want to show the delete button if there is no referential integrity issue/constraint (meaning if there is a pk/fk relation I don't want to show a delete button).

Let's say my child object is BookCategory and the parent object is Book. If a BookCategory is assigned to a Book then don't show the delete button, if there is no relationship then show the button.

Obviously in my case, BookCategory object model doesn't have a reference to Book, I could do that... but it seems a bit of resource waste, but maybe if I lazy load it wouldn't.

I'm trying to figure out a way through jpa / @query etc to allow for the UI to know whether to show the delete button or not.

I am looping through BookCategory(s) on the given page, but of course like I say it doesn't know if it is assigned to a book.

Seems like this thing would need to be done all the time, but not sure best how to build it.

Thanks, Keith

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have many to many connection between the entities.

In your example, you can use a lazy connection to the book and create an entity graph to load it when necessary or use jpql with join fetch.

You have to examine if there is a joined object or not, so you can also write a jpql to count the the joined object.

With Spring Data JPA you can create a composite model with, for example an id list, count... field refer to the books and put the other necessary fields for book category. Then spring data can load this into the model:

```
@Query(" select new com.mypackage.CustomBookCategory(b.name,count(b.book), ...) from BookCategory b where ...")
List<CustomBookCategory> findByCategory(String category);
```